# Spring Boot embedded TomCat failed to start after adding an actuator

Tags: spring-boot, tomcat, spring-boot-actuator

I'm following a tutorial on Springboot and while everything was going fine suddenly after adding actuator into my pom.xml am getting below exception. I don't have any explicit servlet-api as well in it.

### Exception

```
2018-08-12 23:18:02.934 ERROR 2408 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatStarter  : Error starting Tomcat context. Exception: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException. Message: Error creating bean with name 'servletEndpointRegistrar' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/actuate/autoconfigure/endpoint/web/ServletEndpointManagementContextConfiguration$WebMvcServletEndpointManagementContextConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.web.ServletEndpointRegistrar]: Factory method 'servletEndpointRegistrar' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/web/servlet/DispatcherServletPath
2018-08-12 23:18:02.974  INFO 2408 --- [  restartedMain] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Stopping service [Tomcat]
2018-08-12 23:18:02.985  WARN 2408 --- [  restartedMain] ConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Unable to start web server; nested exception is org.springframework.boot.web.server.WebServerException: Unable to start embedded Tomcat
2018-08-12 23:18:03.020  INFO 2408 --- [  restartedMain] ConditionEvaluationReportLoggingListener : 

Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2018-08-12 23:18:03.033 ERROR 2408 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed

org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Unable to start web server; nested exception is org.springframework.boot.web.server.WebServerException: Unable to start embedded Tomcat
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.onRefresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:155) ~[spring-boot-2.0.4.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:2.0.4.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:544) ~[spring-context-5.0.8.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:5.0.8.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:140) ~[spring-boot-2.0.4.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:2.0.4.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:762) [spring-boot-2.0.4.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:2.0.4.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:398) [spring-boot-2.0.4.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:2.0.4.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:330) [spring-boot-2.0.4.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:2.0.4.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1258) [spring-boot-2.0.4.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:2.0.4.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1246) [spring-boot-2.0.4.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:2.0.4.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
    at com.vishnu.rest.webservices.restfulwebservices.RestfulWebServicesApplication.main(RestfulWebServicesApplication.java:17) [classes/:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_161]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_161]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_161]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_161]
    at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartLauncher.run(RestartLauncher.java:49) [spring-boot-devtools-2.0.4.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:2.0.4.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
Caused by: org.springframework.boot.web.server.WebServerException: Unable to start embedded Tomcat
    at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer.initialize(TomcatWebServer.java:126) ~[spring-boot-2.0.4.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:2.0.4.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer.<init>(TomcatWebServer.java:86) ~[spring-boot-2.0.4.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:2.0.4.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatServletWebServerFactory.getTomcatWebServer(TomcatServletWebServerFactory.java:413) ~[spring-boot-2.0.4.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:2.0.4.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatServletWebServerFactory.getWebServer(TomcatServletWebServerFactory.java:174) ~[spring-boot-2.0.4.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:2.0.4.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.createWebServer(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:179) ~[spring-boot-2.0.4.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:2.0.4.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.onRefresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:152) ~[spring-boot-2.0.4.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:2.0.4.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
    ... 13 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'servletEndpointRegistrar' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/actuate/autoconfigure/endpoint/web/ServletEndpointManagementContextConfiguration$WebMvcServletEndpointManagementContextConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.web.ServletEndpointRegistrar]: Factory method 'servletEndpointRegistrar' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/web/servlet/DispatcherServletPath
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:590) ~[spring-beans-5.0.8.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:5.0.8.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1249) ~[spring-beans-5.0.8.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:5.0.8.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1098) ~[spring-beans-5.0.8.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:5.0.8.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:537) ~[spring-beans-5.0.8.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:5.0.8.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:497) ~[spring-beans-5.0.8.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:5.0.8.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:317) ~[spring-beans-5.0.8.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:5.0.8.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222) ~[spring-beans-5.0.8.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:5.0.8.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:315) ~[spring-beans-5.0.8.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:5.0.8.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:204) ~[spring-beans-5.0.8.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:5.0.8.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.ServletContextInitializerBeans.getOrderedBeansOfType(ServletContextInitializerBeans.java:226) ~[spring-boot-2.0.4.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:2.0.4.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.ServletContextInitializerBeans.getOrderedBeansOfType(ServletContextInitializerBeans.java:214) ~[spring-boot-2.0.4.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:2.0.4.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.ServletContextInitializerBeans.addServletContextInitializerBeans(ServletContextInitializerBeans.java:91) ~[spring-boot-2.0.4.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:2.0.4.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.ServletContextInitializerBeans.<init>(ServletContextInitializerBeans.java:80) ~[spring-boot-2.0.4.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:2.0.4.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.getServletContextInitializerBeans(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:250) ~[spring-boot-2.0.4.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:2.0.4.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.selfInitialize(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:237) ~[spring-boot-2.0.4.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:2.0.4.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatStarter.onStartup(TomcatStarter.java:54) ~[spring-boot-2.0.4.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:2.0.4.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5245) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.32.jar:8.5.32]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.32.jar:8.5.32]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1421) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.32.jar:8.5.32]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1411) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.32.jar:8.5.32]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_161]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_161]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_161]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_161]
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.web.ServletEndpointRegistrar]: Factory method 'servletEndpointRegistrar' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/web/servlet/DispatcherServletPath
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:185) ~[spring-beans-5.0.8.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:5.0.8.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:582) ~[spring-beans-5.0.8.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:5.0.8.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
    ... 23 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/web/servlet/DispatcherServletPath
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.endpoint.web.ServletEndpointManagementContextConfiguration$WebMvcServletEndpointManagementContextConfiguration.servletEndpointRegistrar(ServletEndpointManagementContextConfiguration.java:71) ~[spring-boot-actuator-autoconfigure-2.0.4.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:2.0.4.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.endpoint.web.ServletEndpointManagementContextConfiguration$WebMvcServletEndpointManagementContextConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$703b784c.CGLIB$servletEndpointRegistrar$0(<generated>) ~[spring-boot-actuator-autoconfigure-2.0.4.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:2.0.4.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.endpoint.web.ServletEndpointManagementContextConfiguration$WebMvcServletEndpointManagementContextConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$703b784c$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$93242fbb.invoke(<generated>) ~[spring-boot-actuator-autoconfigure-2.0.4.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:2.0.4.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invokeSuper(MethodProxy.java:228) ~[spring-core-5.0.8.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:5.0.8.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.intercept(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:361) ~[spring-context-5.0.8.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:5.0.8.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.endpoint.web.ServletEndpointManagementContextConfiguration$WebMvcServletEndpointManagementContextConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$703b784c.servletEndpointRegistrar(<generated>) ~[spring-boot-actuator-autoconfigure-2.0.4.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:2.0.4.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_161]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_161]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_161]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_161]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:154) ~[spring-beans-5.0.8.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:5.0.8.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
    ... 24 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.servlet.DispatcherServletPath
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_161]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_161]
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_161]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_161]
    ... 35 common frames omitted
```

### pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.vishnu.rest.webservices</groupId>
    <artifactId>restful-web-services</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>restful-web-services</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.4.BUILD-SNAPSHOT</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-data-rest-hal-browser</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-hateoas</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-dataformat-xml</artifactId>
    </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
            <artifactId>springfox-swagger2</artifactId>
            <version>2.4.0</version>            
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
            <artifactId>springfox-swagger-ui</artifactId>
            <version>2.4.0</version>            
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>spring-snapshots</id>
            <name>Spring Snapshots</name>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/snapshot</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <id>spring-milestones</id>
            <name>Spring Milestones</name>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/milestone</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </repository>
    </repositories>

    <pluginRepositories>
        <pluginRepository>
            <id>spring-snapshots</id>
            <name>Spring Snapshots</name>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/snapshot</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </pluginRepository>
        <pluginRepository>
            <id>spring-milestones</id>
            <name>Spring Milestones</name>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/milestone</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </pluginRepository>
    </pluginRepositories>


</project>
```

The **data-rest-hal-broswer** is for reading actuator content in my browser and I don't think that's the culprit.It would be helpful if I get the solution for the above exception.

Comment: Maybe one of your jars is broken. Try to delete the dependencies from .m2 and import it again. By the way, why do you use a snapshot version?

Comment: I got it buddy the broken jar is the culprit,deleted my repository and updated maven boom...! Thanks for your time though!!! For the version I just happened to download the latest one from Springboot starter kit.

Comment: There is no issue in your given pom.xml. I have verified in my system. Kindly remove .m2 repository and try again